# How to grep a very large file containing a single line in parallel?

Tags: regex, parallel-processing, grep

I have a file having only one line. It is large that very time consuming using grep directly. I want to grep all matches and output to stdout (the order is not important). As follows,

```
grep -o "[0-9]+" filename
```

I found that there are answers using the GNU parallel. It is capable of tackle this case? To what I know, the grep command is line-based. It is possible to grep a single line in parallel?

I know, maybe I need a parallel regex matcher, is there any available tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parallel --recend '' --pipepart -a filename --block -1 -q grep -Eo "[0-9]+"
```